# Mount NFS drive during automatic installation

Tags: ubuntu, mount, system-installation, nfs, cloud-init

I am setting up automatic installation (autoinstall / AutoInstallation) of Ubuntu server 20.04 Focal by booting the USB installer and fetching the user-data configuration file from a local http server. The configuration has gone well so far, with partitioning, package installation etc in place.

However, I am not able to mount an NFS drive during the installation and it seems that I should be able to use the *mount* command

https://discourse.maas.io/t/how-to-mount-nfs-volume-via-preseed/1404/2

https://curtin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/storage.html#mount-command

by specifying *spec* instead of *device* but the installation crashes with the message

```
missing 1 required positional argument: 'device'
```

I have tried giving the NFS path using the device argument (along with a bunch of permutations) but with the same result. This is what the entry looks like

```
- type: mount
  path: "/mnt/nfs"
  fstype: "nfs"
  options: "auto,nofail,noatime,nolock,intr,tcp,actimeo=1800,user,suid"
  spec: "192.168.164.58/admin"
  id: mount-admin
  freq: 0
  passno: 0
```

It seems curtin is managed by canonical but could it be that the Ubuntu installer does not adhere completely to the behaviour in the documentation? Any help is much appreciated

I have also tried setting up the mount via the `mounts:` module described here,

https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html?highlight=mounts#mounts

specifying nfs as fstype but this entry seems to be ignored entirely. The connection of cloud-init to the ubuntu server installer is not clear to me although the configuration syntaxes a very similar. Maybe the ubuntu server installer only implements a subset of cloud-init's options? I would appreciate any insights to this

Comment: All of the links that you link to note that the first line syntax is -id: but you have -type: why is that?

Comment: That order has worked in previous entries but it's worth a shot

Comment: changing the order - giving id: first - does not change the behaviour. It is still missing the device argument. I have tried giving device: as an empty string or as null but with the same result